How can I access a mounted blob storage folder from the server to the webpage?
I want to access the files from my mounted blob storage folder named nfsdata and is located in my root folder of the server.
So I tried using:
src="/nfsdata/image.jpg" from html image tag but it's not working.
I also tried src="../../../../nfsdata/image.jpg" and it's also not working. I thought this might work because my website files are saved in /var/www/html/website.
If you mounted the blob storage as a folder, is it considered as a local folder?
How can I access the files like a local folder?

In your side, How you are mounting azure blob storage?

I am mounting Azure Blob Storage indirectly through NFS.
My Azure Blob Storage endpoint is mounted at /nfsdata

@バッカマル  Refer Mount Blob Storage by using the Network File System (NFS) 3.0 protocol .

Thank you for all your answers. I found out why I can't access the files in my nfsdata from my webpage: because my nfsdata is located outside my www root. I set up a symbolic link of nfsdata inside my /var/www/html, and now it's working.
